# Is it better to have 2 different entities (with similar FKs, PKs) or combine them into 1big entity?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, erd

I've created an ERD for my project about gymnastic clubs (school project).
Everything was fine until I wanted to create additional tables as *CompetitionResult* & *Attendance*.
My project is about creating an API for a gymnastic club.
My project is ASP .Net Core (with EF implementation)

Describing the entities and logic

- *Gymnasts*  have single *gymgroup*(FK) and those *gymgroups* have multiple *gymevents*.
- *GymEvent* have multiple *gymgroups*(FK), multiple *CompetitionResults*, and multiple *Attendances*.
- *CompetitionResults* have single *gymevent*(FK), single *gymnast*(FK) (also, *Id*(PK), *points* and an enum for result)
- *Attendance* has single *gymevent*(FK), single *gymnast*(FK) (also *Id*(PK) and an attendancestatus -> enum)

My question as described in the title, how to store those data properly.

Should I stick to having an Id as a PK? For example:

**CompetitionResult**

- *From: Id(PK), GymEvent(FK), Gymnast(FK)*
- *To: GymEvent(PK,FK) / Gymnast(PK,FK)*

Or should I combine those tables into one?
So like CompetitionResults will have an AttendanceStatus or otherwise?

Here is the ERD

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKzVT.png

Comment: This is really a question about design. They are difficult to answer because they are often subjective. It might help if you rephrase the question so it better highlights the problem you have and makes it separate from your project details. For example 'Is it better to make 2 different entities or combine together when they contain few properties and there is a close to 1-1 mapping between them?'

Comment: @mikelegg ,thank you for the tip. I get that it's somewhere subjective but I don't feel like it's a correct way to go for me , while I can't think of anything else. So I need a little advice to get some workaround.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use multiple tables instead of using one big table. Because, using one big table, it might cause redundant data, and different entities might have the inconsistent dependencies. I suggest you could check the [Description of the database normalization basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description).